# What are the differences between Linear Regression in Machine Learning and Linear Regression in Statistics?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression

I am wondering what the differences are for linear regression in a machine learning context versus a statistical context.
Are there any conditions that are assumed and need to be checked in statistics and not assumed in machine learning?

As dar as I know, in statistics, the errors are assumed to be distributed normal with the mean of zero and the cariance of 1. I don't know why it is assumed like that and I don't know what else is assumed. Does Machine Learning also assume the same thing to build a linear regression?

Comment: [Statistical Learning from a Regression Perspective](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387775005) ([review](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v029b12) in the JSS). But I suspect this is a rather vague question: Why wouldn't we assume the same conditions for the exact same model? Would you mind clarifying what you're thinking?

Comment: I think you have to distinguish between fitting (e.g. least squares) and learning on the one hand and inference on the other hand: If you add assumptions about the errors, you may specify confidence intervals, ... for predicted values. In case of linear regression see e.g. Kutner, "Applied linear statistical models".